# Option instead of assignment

Tags: sas

I have to write a program that reads the data after datalines; in the code part. As you can see i use a assignment to remove the '',$ and the ** in the provided data. However i have to do the program without an assignment, which is quite troublesome. Any ideas on how to change it, so the program reads the code, but ignores '',$ and the **?

Cheers

```
data PERSONELL;
input @; 
  if not index(_infile_,'****');
  _infile_ = translate(_infile_,' ','$');
  length ID $ 4;
  length DEPT $ 1;
  input ID $ @1 DEPT $ BIRTHDAY date10. +(-5) YEAR :8. Salary comma8./;
  datalines;
A123  4Mar1989  8,6,00
***************
    A037 23Jun1957  21,450
**************
 M015 19Sep1977$17,500
***********
;
run;
```

Comment: Is this homework or a test question ? Why can't you use an assignment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can assume that every value is present (that is missing values are represented by period) then use the `dlm=` option on the `infile` statement to  tell SAS to treat `$` and `*` the same as spaces.

```
data PERSONELL;
  length id $4 dept $1 birthday 8 year 8 salary 8;
  infile datalines dlm=' $*';
  informat birthday date. salary comma.;
  input id birthday salary ;
  year=year(birthday);
  dept=id;
  format birthday date9.;
datalines;
A123  4Mar1989  8,6,00
***************
    A037 23Jun1957  21,450
**************
 M015 19Sep1977$17,500
***********
;
```

Results

```
Obs     id     dept     birthday    year    salary

 1     A123     A      04MAR1989    1989      8600
 2     A037     A      23JUN1957    1957     21450
 3     M015     M      19SEP1977    1977     17500
```